# Backtracking algorithm crashes with hard cases (C)

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, backtracking

I am actually making an algorithm that takes as an input a file containing tetriminoses (figures from tetris) and arranges them in smallest possible square.

Still I encounter a weird problem :

The algorithm works for less than 10 tetriminoses (every time) but start crashing with 11, 12... (I concluded that it depends on how complicated the solution is, as it finds some 14 and 15 solutions).

But the thing is, if I add an optimisation flag like -Ofast (the program is written in C) it works for every input I give him no matter how much time it takes (sometimes more than a hour..).
First I had a lot of leaks (I was using double linked list) so I changed for an Int Array, no more leaks, but same problem.
I tried using the debugger but it makes no sense (see picture) :

[Debugger says my variables do not exist anymore but all I do is increment or decrement them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH6zU.png)

[For this example it just stopped while everything is fine (values of variables are correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iOS7.png)

Here is the link of my main function (the one that do the backtracking):

https://github.com/Caribou123/fillitAG/blob/master/19canplace/solve.c

The rest of program (same repository) consist of functions to put tetriminoses in my array, remove them from it, or print the result.

Basically I try placing a tetri, if I have enough space, I place the next one, otherwise I remove the last one and place it to the next available position etc..

Also I first thought that I were trying to place something outside of the Array, so now my Array is way bigger than it should be and filled with -1 for invalid cases (so in the worst case I just rewrite a -1), 0 for free ones, and integers values from 1 to 26 for figures.

The fact that the program works with the flag -Ofast really troubles me, as the algorithm seems to work perfectly, what could cause my program to crash ?

[Here is how I tracked the number of recursions, by adding two static variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbHZk.png)

[And here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RkY5.png)

(In case you want to test it yourself, use the 19canplace folder, and compile with : gcc *.c libft/libft.a)

Thanks in advance for your time,

Artiom

Comment: Maybe try **valgrind** to check your program http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

Comment: Already tried, nothing alarming, at least to me.

Comment: `ft_solve()` is a recursive function. Have you checked what the maximum recursion depth is when your program works and when it crashes? Depending on what system the code is running you might run into stack overflow issues. A simple debugging method would be to track in a static variable the latest maximum recursion depth and print out a line when a new maximum depth has been reached?

Comment: One reason why the problem goes away with -Ofast might be that the optimizer detects the recursion and eliminates it, see f.ex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Comment: Thanks for the tracks : I tried to track the number of recursions, i'll add pictures of the implementation in my thread.
Correct me if I am wrong, the idea of tail_call would be to reduce the number of returns to just one instead of three ?
Also what do you mean by eliminate recursion ?

Comment: Tail call optimization will pop off the current stack frame, including arguments, and, preserving the return address. It will then replace it with the arguments for the function to be called and the return address, and _jump_ to the new function rather than _call_ it. Thus the stack pointer is only adjusted slightly and doesn't need to grow on each call

Comment: I feel rely confused, I tried to implement an iterative version, it took me 5 mins and now it works perfectly ! For some reason I was convinced I had to use recursion.
Anyway I'll keep preciously your links to tail recursion for next time as it seems important.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad you found the iterative solution. FYI, I pulled down your `solve.c` and added dummy functions to make it compilable. I then disassembled it to look at the instructions it generated. Without optimization, `ft_solve` had several x86 asm `call` instructions, including recursive . With `-O2` [similar to `-Ofast`], it had _none_. I also did an iterative version and it also took me about 5 minutes ;-) IMO, recursion can be overused and [again, IMO] it starts with teachers giving assignments that ask students to calculate factorial recursively :-)

Comment: You are not tracking the recursion depth but how many times `ft_solve()` is called. You need to add `k` as parameter to `ft_solve()` and then update all recursive calls to read `ft_solve(k + 1, ...)`.

Comment: What are x86 asm call ?